# Distributed notification centre not working between Non-Arc & Arc target?

Tags: objective-c, macos, automatic-ref-counting

I am new to MacOS development. I am working on existing developed product. They were implemented that project in Non-Arc. In Arc all modules are working fine. Now we are trying to implemented Arc for new modules. If we are using NSDistributionNotification centre using to communicate between Arc & Non-Arc modules. When i am running all the modules and posting data using notifications from Non-Arc to Arc targets. This time notification is not able to send data from Non-Arc to Arc targets.

Example:

Target1(module 1) --> Arc (Added NSDistributionNotificationCentre observer)

Target2(module 2) --> Non-Arc (Posting data to target1 using NSDistributionNotificationCentre).

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think ARC should affect distributed notifications.

Two possible reasons I can think of:

- The observer gets released and thus does not receive the notifications.
  Check that its instance is actually live and did not get deallocated.
- If observer is sandboxed, it’s not allowed to receive distributed notifications with `userInfo`.

Comment: Same non arc notifiers receiving notifications which are posting from another non arc targets.